# Remove a scratch from powder coated mailbox

Tags: paint

I have an ugly scratch on my mailbox. According to the [manufacture](https://www.mailboss.com/shop/wall-mount-mailboxes/locking-security-drop-box/), it has a powder coat. Here is a picture I am enclosing,
[image]

It is rather unsightly, what can I use to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably try a car-paint touch-up  product.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Do you have a particular brand you prefer?